# Grid with moving items

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

How can I do a Grid Control in which I can move the items (the content) inside by mouse drag & drop?
For instance move something from A1  to B4, like in Excel.

I'm using C#, NET 3.5, and Winforms.

Answer (score 0):

Gridview is for showing contents in a columnwise and rowwise manner.

What is the use of dragging and dropping one item in one column to another column?

Comment: if was the first control that looked similar to what I need. I need a table in which I can move items by drap and drop.
Best would be if the rows are splitted by line or something but you still can move the items over that line.